# Earliest optimal random integer algorithm?

Tags: math-history, random

In September 2021, Stephen Canon published [an algorithm](https://twitter.com/stephentyrone/status/1433503475401363466) to derive random integers from a random bitstream, achieving maximal efficiency *wrt* bits consumed in the single-draw case.

> This [Pull Request] introduces a novel algorithm that:
>
> - never divides
> - avoids rejection sampling entirely
> - achieves a theoretically optimal bound on the amount of randomness consumed to generate a sample

He cites [previous work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10941) that achieved unbiased output but failed to achieve optimality of entropy consumed in the single-draw case.

Not cited, Canon's algorithm appears to be identical to (*i.e.* an independent re-discovery of) the ["fast dice roller" introduced by Jérémie Lumbroso in April 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1916):

> This article introduces an algorithm to draw random discrete uniform variables within a given range of size n from a source of random bits. The algorithm aims to be simple to implement and optimal [with] regards to the amount of random bits consumed …

My question is: was Lumbroso really the first person in history to publish this algorithm, or had someone beat him to the discovery, too?